# couchdb reduce on non-key value

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchdb

I have a data set in couchdb with multiple documents that list a timestamp and a set of signals from sensors. In this example I've only used a few different names, but there can be an infinite amount of different names as additional sensors are added to the system. Here's an example of three sample documents:

```
{ timestamp: 12345,
  signals: ["highTemperature", "highPressure"]
}

{ timestamp: 12346,
  signals: ["highTemperature"]
}

{ timestamp: 12347,
  signals: ["lowPressure", "highTemperature"]
}
```

What I'd like to be able to do is to get the frequency of each tag. A simple way to do this is to create a map function like this:

```
function (doc) {
  for (var idx in doc.signals) {
  emit(doc.signals[idx], 1);
}
```

Along with a reduce function like this:

```
function(signal, counts) {
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
    sum += counts[i]; 
  };
  return sum; 
}
```

This will return a nice set of data like this:

```
{"rows":[
  {"key":"highTemperature","value":3},
  {"key":"highPressure","value":1},
  {"key":"lowPressure","value":1}
]}
```

This is great if I wanted to know the signal distribution over all time, but I really want to know is the distribution of tags for a subset of data points, say timestamp 12346 - 12349.  However, what I can't do is slice the data by timestamp using `startkey` and `endkey` because timestamp is not part of a key. If I make timestamp is the key then I can't reduce to get a distribution of signals.

Is there a way to do such a grouping so you reduce on an element that isn't part of the key? Ideally I'd like to specify the grouping interval via a URL parameter such as: `/mydb/_design/main/_view/signalsByTime?startkey=12346&endkey=12347` and have it return the distribution of signals for just that time period, like this:

```
{"rows":[
  {"key":"highTemperature","value":2},
  {"key":"lowPressure","value":1}
]}
```

Comment: How would you like to specify the grouping interval?

Comment: Edited the question to clarify. I'd like to use startkey and endkey to specify the range of timestamps for which I should aggregate the signals. Functionally this would be really easy if I could have have the a view emit(doc.timestamp, doc.signal[idx]) and then run a reduce on the (value, key) set instead of the (key, value) set.

Comment: OK, I'm not that good at views.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `timestamp` to be the key and number of possible signals is very small (`O(1)`, lets assume 3 as in your example), then you can emit in `map` characteristic vector of your signal:

```
if (doc.signal == "highTemperature") {
  emit(doc.timestamp, [1,0,0]);
} else if (doc.signal == "highPressure") {
  emit(doc.timestamp, [0,1,0]);
} ...
```

and sum-up vectors in `reduce`, possibly like this:

```
function(keys, values) {
  var sum = [0,0,0];
  for (v in values) {
    for (s in sum) {
      sum[s] += values[v][s];
    }
  }
  return sum; 
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer for when the set of potential signals is small, but in my system set is actually very very large and can grow at any time. This is a very good answer, but it just doesn't quite solve my problem, but that's mainly because I wasn't clear enough about my problem in the first case.

Comment: Can you predict anything about the queries? Perhaps some bounds on the range you will select, some grain, e.g. the timestamp is always rounded to minutes, the range does not span more then one hour, etc.? Dynamic arbitrary queries does not seem to me what Couch is designed for.